# While-loop in c

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

what is different between while(0) and while (1 or another number ) ??

```
int main() {
   do {
      printf("Math ");
   } while (0);

   printf("Computer");
}
```

Comment: When you tried, what did you observe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros)

Answer (score 4):

`while (cond) { ... }` and `do { ... } while (cond);` execute the loop as long as the condition is true. The former checks the condition before each pass of the loop, while the latter checks the condition after each pass of the loop.

`0` is a false value.

`1` and other numbers are true values.

`while (0) { ... }` is useless. It's a loop that will never be executed.

`while (1) { ... }` is a infinite loop. Something like `break`, `return` or `exit` is needed to leave it.

`do { ... } while (0);` is a weird way of writing `{ ... }`.<sup>[1]</sup>

`do { ... } while (1);` is a weird way of writing `while (1) { ... }`.

---

1. `do { ... } while (0)` has use [in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/589924).

Comment: `do {} while(0)` is not weird way and it is needed in the multi statement macros as in my answer

Comment: @P__J__, 1) I said `do { ... } while (0);` was weird. You did not use that in your macro. 2) Even if it's useful in that situation, that doesn't make it make it any less weird. /// But yeah, that use is good to know, though far too advanced for the OP.

Comment: @ikegami It's actually common practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros for example.

Comment: @gst, 1) That doesn't use `do { ... } while (0);` 2) I know it's common to use `do { ... } while (0)` in macros. I'm not sure why you're telling me that.

Comment: @ikegami . *I'm not sure why you're telling me that* - because from your answer we do not feel that you know that. BTW I do not use it too often as I bare myself if I only can from that kind of macros (prefer `inline` functions)

Comment: @P__J__, gst claimed (through the use of "actually") that I said it wasn't common practice (to use it in macros). Nothing in my answer or subsequent comments said that. So again, I have no idea why they claimed that.

Comment: @ikegami the word `weird` suggests that (at least I feel it this way)

Comment: @P__J__, 1) For the third time, I said `do { ... } while (0);` is weird, but the macros don't use `do { ... } while (0);`.  2) `do { ... } while (0)` is a hack to make multi-statement macros appear as a single statement. That is weird usage of a loop, even if common. 3) I've also already stated that I think it's inappropriate to confuse the OP with this. But I've added a footnote

Answer (score 1):

in C all non zero values are the "**true**" and zero is "**false**". So if the number is used as the logical expression it acts as the logical value of `true` or `false`. You can even use pointers as a logical values

```
char *ptr;
if(*ptr)
{
   //do something if ptr is not NULL 
}
else
{
   //do something if ptr is NULL 
}
```

The `do {... } while(0)` is used in the multi statement macros. Why?

Lets analyze the `if` statement:

```
if(condition)
    macro(x);
  else
   foo();
```

if the `macro` is just the simple compound statement like:

`#define macro(x) {x *= 2; printf("%d\n",x);}`
then the `if` statement will not compile

but if we define the macro this way:

`#define macro(x) do{x *= 2; printf("%d\n",x);}while(0)`

everything is fine and syntactically OK.

You can test it yourself here:
https://godbolt.org/z/RW7Zmo

`do {...} while(0)` will execute only once as the condition is checked after the statements inside the `{}`